# node js (javascript) code doesn't call function but instead shows the code as text

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I created a module for node js and connected it to the main file, then ran the server in localhost:8080. The code ran but, this happened-

[display of localhost:8080](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9NRj.png)

this is the code for the main node.js file-

```
var http = require('http');
var dt = require('./demo_module.js');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
  res.write("Date and time:" + dt.myDateTime)
  res.end('Hello World!');
}}.listen(8080;)
```

The code for module-

```
exports.myDateTime = function () {
return Date();
};
```

Comment: "display of localhost:8080" is the link to the screenshot of what happened

Comment: `res.write("Date and time:" + dt.myDateTime)` -> you need to actually call your function: `dt.myDateTime()`

Comment: You didn't call the function

Answer (score 1):

This is a function, you need to call it otherwise it will just print the function

```js
exports.myDateTime = function () {
  return Date();
};
```

Change to this:

```js
res.write("Date and time:" + dt.myDateTime());
```